# Redmine: how to list issues ordered by priority in Gantt view?

Tags: redmine

I have many projects on Redmine, including issues and subprojects.
In Gantt view, issues are grouped by projects, and projects are listed by alphabetic order.

How to list issues ordered by priority in Gantt view? I mean all the issues (not filtered) just ordered.

This user has administrator permissions on this installation.

```
Environment:
  Redmine version                4.0.4.stable
Redmine plugins:
  no plugin installed
```

Comment: I've tried to apply a custom query that includes a "Sort by: Priority" component. But it doesn't appear that the Gantt display respects that. If you are comfortable modifying the code, you could try making a change to the display routine -- possibly in `gantt_helper.rb`. Something similar is discussed [here](https://www.redmine.org/issues/7335).

Comment: A plugin that claims to have better sorting is available [here](https://github.com/kulesa/redmine_better_gantt_chart). It's old, but it might still work.